# IE7 and 8 Hangs Randomly on CSS Images

Tags: asp.net, css, internet-explorer, iis, diagnostics

We have an ASP.NET 3.5 application that has been in production for over a year.  Our last release was a couple of months ago.  We use CSS for styling and application of background images to divs and such.  The server is Windows 2003 with IIS.

Suddenly, this week, we have had reports from some users that the page seems to hang up while loading.  The status bar was showing the name of a background image used in the page main area (assigned in CSS). At our office, some of us could recreate the problem, while others could not.  IE6 and Firefox do not seem to be affected, only IE7/8.  Running Fiddler on an affected machine and trying to see what was happening with the requests seemed to make the problem go away (while running through Fiddler, it returned when not).  Hitting Refresh on a hung load often made the page load just fine.

I checked the background image, and even replaced it with an archived copy.  No joy.  We re-deployed the app from our production source.  No Joy.  We restarted IIS and eventually rebooted the whole server.  There are no unusual entries in the event logs, the app logs or the IIS logs.  Finally, I removed the image entirely and re-styled the page not to use a background image. That solved the problem at least for now.

However, we have reports of other images "hanging."  The images are PNGs, but I have heard some rumors that sometimes a GIF hangs, but I have no screenshot to confirm.

This just started happening "out of the blue." There have been no releases or updates applied to the server recently.  We even checked updates on clients to see if a recent Windows Update might have caused this on the client, but there was nothing updated within the last couple of weeks.

If you have any information about this problem, I would love to hear from you.  I would also greatly appreciate any recommendations on additional diagnostics we can try.

Comment: do you have a link to ur website/testbed/sandbox?

Comment: Sadly for this kind of Q&A, this site is a subscription site and you need a login id.  We don't really have an open testbed/sandbox.

Comment: BTW, the GIF hang has been confirmed at least on one machine.

Comment: Probably network or operating system issue. Use Ctrl+F5 to force IE to reload (not refresh) the page when testing. Any virus software installed on clients or server or network? Any backup software or cloning software on server? Is servers "virtual machines"? Does this happen on same subnet? Does this happen internally or external? Any recent firewall changes? You use proxy servers? I doubt IE/CSS/ASP.NET issue; otherwise, answer would be on web. Could be bad images. Recreate as jpeg, test, then recreate from jpeg to png, test. What software used to create png? Try different software.

Comment: To clarify: the page stops loading when the image is being rendered/downloaded? Does the part of the page which is already loaded continue to work? Is the browser hung? And can you post some of the CSS/HTML snippets that you changed to work around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the images hosted on the same server/website as the main site? Could it be a network/DNS issue?

Comment: The images are hosted on the same server in a subdirectory within the web site. Single server, no web farm.

Comment: I am marking Garry's answer because he was the first to suggest network/DNS.  I am not sure what the actual problem was, but when we moved to the new data center and hardware, the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

Can I suggest you look harder at your PNG version / content?

PNG files support alpha-channels, which provide a form of transparency.  IE 6 does NOT support alpha channels and therefore may be processing your images differently.  IE 7 & 8 do support alpha channels.

Comment: Several things come to mind.  First, the images work fine in IE6, so I am not sure why they would fail with the better support for Alpha channels in IE7/8.  Second, I don't think the image I ended up having to remove had any transparent areas, it was just a shadowed left and right border with an off-white center area. However, I am open to all ideas, so I will double-check to see if this might be a factor.

Comment: I think Allan's point is that maybe something's wrong with alpha channels that IE6 doesn't run into because it ignores all alphas.  It's a long shot, but worth trying.  Try saving a non-alpha version of the PNG or exporting it from a known good PNG exporter like Adobe Fireworks to see if anything changes.

Comment: I have been prepping for a server move this week, so this issue went on a back-burner. I am getting Photoshop this week, so we will be able to check performance on the new server _and_ try recreating the images in Photoshop.

Answer (score 0):

Are the image names camelCased or PascalCased by chance? We had issues with images that were not all lowercased. Also, if you move to a CDN such as S3, you will want everything to be lowercased (just in case).

Pls post CSS and an obfuscated path to the file.

Comment: The images are all lower-case, with dashes. I'll try to post some css snippets later today.

Answer (score 0):

Does this happen on both your Intranet and outside sources?  Has this been tested outside the internal network?  (This sounds like it may be related to DNS.)

Comment: The connections are all internet.  The server was in a data center and was not directly connected to any internal network.  Coincidentally, we are upgrading to a new server in a new facility this weekend, so perhaps this will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of possibilities for this bug obviously, but I faced the problem, I was able to fix the problem, and so I thought I would share with the community my fix.

I had something like

```
background-image: url("/myapp/images/expand_title_off.gif"); 
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
background-position: center center;
```

inside of a style attribute for a span element.

For IE7, I combined all of these into a single background property like

```
background:url("/myapp/images/expand_title_off.gif") no-repeat center center;
```

IE7 did not look too kindly on trying to use the specific properties.  For me, both the old and the new styles worked just fine with chrome, so definitely an IE7 issue.